# Why there is no sun-java in Debian Wheezy and how can I fix this?

Tags: debian, java, sun-java6-jdk, debian-wheezy

Sun's java is in Debian Lenny and Debian Squeeze repos (non-free) but no in wheezy<sup>[1](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/sun-java6-bin),[2](http://packages.qa.debian.org/s/sun-java6.html)</sup>. Why?

**edit**: after further research I found that java has been removed. reson:

> ROM; security issues and newer versions cannot be redistributed <sup>[3](http://packages.qa.debian.org/s/sun-java6/news/20111025T091708Z.html)</sup>

The following question remains:

**Where do I get sun-java packages for Debian Wheezy?**

Comment: it's funny that while googling one of the first results is [this](http://superuser.com/questions/368428) page

Comment: SU indexes quickly! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure that it is because of licensing reasons, since the Sun/Oracle Java is in both Squeeze and Sid.

If you need Sun/Oracle Java on Wheezy, the easiest way is probably to install the Squeeze or Sid version.  You can make `apt` to do that for you by [pinning](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences).

> Pinning allows you to run certain packages from one version (stable, testing, unstable) without the necessity of upgrading your entire system.

I don't do that at the moment, since I find the `opendjk` packages adequate for all I need, but I did use pinning in the past for number of other packages.

Comment: Is's been removed in sid.

Comment: Packages from Squeeze are working.

Answer (score 4):

In http://wiki.debian.org/Java there is a link to a helper to generate debian packages from upstream tarballs.

This is maybe the best answer: generating a package each time the people at Oracle generate a new version, but I prefer a different one: having a package with scripts to do the tedious task of installing from a tar.gz.

This is why I have generated a package that does not contain the java framework, but which tells the system just the contrary.

In this way I can upgrade just by manually downloading the tar.gz and running an script.

I know that the package and the script can be improved, but for me is more than enough. It works in i386 and amd64.

If you wanna try it you can download it from 
http://babel.ls.fi.upm.es/~vpablos/others/packages/debian/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the right way to install `sun-java`, but this is my (not so good) solution for Wheezy.

In this example, my Java version is JDK 64 bit.

1. Download `jdk-6u30-linux-x64.bin` from [www.oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com)
2. Extract `jdk-6u30-linux-x64.bin` to `/usr/lib/jvm`

   ```
   cp jdk-6u30-linux-x64.bin /usr/lib/jvm
   cd /usr/lib/jvm
   chmod 777 jdk-6u30-linux-x64.bin
   ./jdk-6u30-linux-x64.bin
   rm jdk-6u30-linux-x64.bin
   ```
3. Create a symbolic link to the new directory `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_30`

   ```
   ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_30 /usr/lib/jvm/java-sun
   ```

   (This will save time for the next updates. Just remove the link `/usr/lib/jvm/java-sun` and create the new symbolic link.)
4. Create symbolic links for the web browser:

   ```
   ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-sun/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/javaplugin.so
   ```

   Test with a web browser pointing to `www.java.com`

   ```
   rm /usr/bin/java
   ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-sun/bin/java /usr/bin/java
   rm /usr/bin/javac
   ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-sun/bin/javac /usr/bin/javac
   ```

   and so on..

Hope you find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `java-package` to build a deb from the upstream tarballs, as explained in the [Debian wiki Java/Sun](https://wiki.debian.org/Java/Sun) page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install the packages for Ubuntu.

You can get them [here](http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/s/sun-java6/) (edited).

Currently sun-java is in the *partner* repository, not in the *multiverse* as it was previously.

You will notice that there is no version for Ubuntu 11.10. Same problem as with Debian, I think.

Comment: Sorry, they're not working :/

Comment: You are right. Edited to put the correct link.